# Inherit a class with same namespace and same class name

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, namespaces, .net-assembly

I manage to work it out in 2 Classes, but I failed in 3.
Let's say I have an assembly A.DLL which have namespace = "City" and a class= "NY"

(I will refer this class in my question as "A")

In My new project My namespace is = "City" and I have a class = "NY" (I will refer this class in my question as "B")

So to implement B : A (B Inherit/Extend from A)
I created an alies to the reference A.DLL
and in "B" class refere with "extern alias oldDll"

```
namespace City
{
    extern alias oldDll;

    public class NY : oldDll::City.NY
    {
        public NY() : base()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine! :)

The problem is when I try to use the new assebmly (B.DLL / "B" class) in another assembly with have a reference only to B.DLL (I will refer this class in my question as "C") and create a new intance of "City.NY"
I get an exception, I think it's because "A.DLL" is not loading.

How can I load it (if this is the problem) from B? I don't have access the "C.EXE" or C codes (He is only creating City.NY from B.DLL).
*Note: I cant re compile C. I can only run it.

So I have a class "C" which create a class "B" which inherits from "A"

I thought of manualy load "A.DLL" assembly in "B" code, but the first thing that happens is the base() constructor.. :\

Thanks for helping

Comment: Good question *but* the way you present it makes it more difficult to understand than is necessary. For example, **1.** instead of describing your namespaces and classes in text, why not describe it in code? (For example: "In A.dll: `namespace City { class NY { … } }`") **2.** Why not line up your extern aliases and class references with their actual names? If you have a `A.dll`, why name the extern alias `oldDll`? Why not `A`? Why refer to `A.dll`'s `City.NY` class as "A" when you could call it `A::City.NY`? That way readers of your question would have to perform far less mental juggling. ;)

Comment: @stakx thanks I'll remember it for next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me anyone because I'm not 100% sure but usually you have to reference both assemblies to get it working(that's way some packages have dependencies, which also have to be downloaded and referenced in project).

I think it won't compile either without missing assembly.

Comment: C.dll might have been compiled against a version of B.dll that did not require A.dll and it that case you would not get a compiler error.

Comment: @Kamo I can't re-compile "C", I just running the "C.EXE"

Comment: @Georg - sure but the author said `So I have a class "C" which create a class "B" which inherits from "A"` - in this case I assume B references A.

Comment: @Jumpy_Goat - ok but you know what is this mysterious `A.dll`? Why can't you recompile your C? It's hard to change anything of fix it if you don't have the source.

Comment: @Kamo Maybe a previous version of B did not inherit from A and it that case, the reference to A.dll would not have been required.

Comment: @Kamo , Yeah I now its hard :) , In the example I give I know what C does and what A does.
But I want to ask if this thing is posible if I can't change C and A.
And want to create B that will be something like a "Man In The Middle" such the C will think the B is A, and B will "talk" to A

Comment: @Jumpy_Goat - I think there are already answers which tells you this is not possible :) I you have chain references, you cannot just fold your eyes and pretend you have all that is required. Like I said in my answer - if assembly references another assembly it depends on it - dependencies are always required.

Comment: @Kamo , I have to correct you. dependencies are not always require. In case I dont inherit I can load the assembly dynamicly and invoke his method. This works for me in this scenario, but the code look ugly. using something like the "Adapter" design pattern. But I wanted to use inherit guess its not possible

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that happens is actually not the base constructor but the type constructor. You can specify this with the following:

```
static B()
{
}
```

Note that access modifiers are not allowed on type constructors. But either way, I guess the base type is loaded even before that, so you don't have a chance here.

Also configuration files won't help. They can redirect existing references (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I don't think they can add references that were not there before.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Simply stated - having class `City.NY` in `B.dll` inherit from `City.NY` in `A.dll` is a breaking change that would require the recompilation of assemblies that depend on `B.dll`.

Comment: recompilation whould'nt help... You ment adding reference to the other DLL an recompile right?

Comment: In recompiling other assemblies, they would need to have a reference to A.DLL or would result in a compiler error.

Comment: I'm ~90% sure you would be able to do something with  dynamic loading and reflecting to get it done but, code would be fugley.